# UIButton User Defined Run Time Attributes Does not Work

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, xcode6, calayer

I am trying to draw a border around a custom UIButton.
This doesn't work:
[image]

why?

Answer (score 11):

*[click here to solve the problem](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/30/xcode-runtime-attributes/)*

**Please allow me to repeat it here..^_^**

***The runtime attribute feature allows us to set a UIColor type, which we need to translate to a CGColor type.*** To accomplish this, we need to extend the CALayer class with a property that will translate the UIColor to the CGColor we need for the border and shadow.

You can extend classes in Objective-C using a category. I added two properties called borderIBColor and shadowIBColor that are of type UIColor. The IB stands for interface builder. I have to give these properties a unique name to avoid name conflicts with the original properties called borderColor and shadowColor that are of the type CGColor.

Please see the following code.

**CALayer+RuntimeAttribute.h**

```
@import QuartzCore;

@interface CALayer (IBConfiguration)

@property(nonatomic, assign) UIColor *borderIBColor;

@end
```

**CALayer+RuntimeAttribute.m**

```
@implementation CALayer (IBConfiguration)

- (void)setBorderIBColor:(UIColor *)color {
    self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

- (UIColor *)borderIBColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.borderColor];
}

@end
```

Finally, when you set the ***borderColor*** of runtime attribute feature in xib or storyboard, please set ***borderIBColor*** instead of ***borderColor***. It looks like **layer.borderIDColor**

Have your fun.

Answer (score 4):

cornerRadius & cornerRadius is CGFloat, use Number to change.

borderColor is CGColor, can't be change by Runtime Attribute. (you can add a category to support UIColor to change CGColor)

Helper Category:

UIView+IBHelper.h:

```
@interface UIView (IBHelper)

- (void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)color;

@end
```

UIView+IBHelper.m:

```
@implementation UIView (IBHelper)

- (void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

@end
```

and use borderColor in Runtime Attribute. directly

[image]

Comment: this is crazy that you have to do all this just to add a border color to a button. i dont care if i get down voted for saying this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the layer.masksToBounds = true property, after assigning the other properties.
It worked for me.

Comment: Do you mean in code or in UIBuilder's "User Defined Runtime Attributes"?  Because in the later, this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 solution for UIBuilder lovers:**

#1 For UIButton it's stuck in CGColor world, but the User Defined Runtime Attributes only offer UIColor choices.  Those protocols don't match, so your borders won't show up bc there's no color.  Fix:

In your viewDidLoad programmatically set the borderColor using...

```
myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

#2  Make sure all other attributes (borderWidth, cornerRadius) have 'layer' in the format.  so should be layer.cornerRadius Number 1 [ see pic ]

#3. You don't need maskToBounds

Figure 1: Left-to-Right = result, storyboard, UDRA "code"
[image]